# How to loop through checkboxes in a div that has another div in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several divs like this:

```
<div class="option">
    <div class="optionHeader">Header</div>
    <input type="checkbox">Test 1
    <input type="checkbox">Test 2
</div>
<div class="option">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
</div>
<div class="option">
    <div class="optionHeader">Final Option</div>
    <input type="checkbox">Final Option 1
    <input type="checkbox">Final Option 2
</div>
```

What I want to do is create a loop for each of the checkboxes which have a class of optionHeader within the div.

I tried this:

```
$('.optionHeader').parent('.option').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){

});
```

But it doesn't initiate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.option:has(.optionHeader) input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    // do your code
});
```

Here, `:has(.optionHeader)` selector is considering only those `.options` that contains `.optionHeader`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3x8n8pcp/1/)**

Ref: ***[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)***